# How to send SNS notification after cloud formation is completed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to send a SNS notification after the CFT completion in AWS ? Is there any way to get the progress of the launching CFT in AWS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When create resources using a CF template there is an Advanced section of the Options menu. From there you can set Notification options using SNS and Topics.

When you start the CF process you can also view the status and importantly where the template might have failed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to set up notifications from within the template itself?

Comment: You can do this using the CloudFormation SNS topic resource: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html

Comment: @Mac Did you ever figure out how to do it in the template? The link doesn't make it clear how to bind certain events to a particular SNS

Comment: @VirtualJJ

The AWS::SNS::Topic resource is for creating topics and attaching subscribers to them, not publishing to an existing topic. To publish to an existing topic, you have to use stack options via "Advanced" section in the aws console as shown in the screen shots above, or there is a command line option for this too. Bottom line is I don't think you can do this after a stack is deployed and I don't think you can configure it from the template itself, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Nice example on how to parse this notification messages with an AWS lambda function => https://github.com/guardian/cf-notify/blob/master/lambda_notify.py

Comment: From stack itself you can create custom inline-lambda and call that lambda during the execution of the stack. You can define every other resource as needed for this to be created and lambda inline call will be created only once all other succeeded. You can pass in stack id to this lambda and do whatever needed inside lambda, e.g. pass stack id to SQS with some seconds of delay and post that message is delivered to some lambda check if stack is already success or not and if not done yet, deliver message back to sqs and try again after couple seconds. In any case way out may be inline lambda.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot specify notification ARNs via a CloudFormation template itself. You can  specify them if you use the console to create the stack creation. But you cannot use the console to update the ARNs once the stack has been created. You can, however, use aws-cli to update the stack with notifications ARNs once it has been created, eg:

`aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name stack-name --use-previous-template --notification-arns "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:${ACCOUNT_ID}:${TOPIC_NAME}"`

Replace the variable `${VARIABLE}` with the literal values from your account.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [knowledge center article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-rollback-email/) from AWS where you can replace ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS statement with any other state of CloudFormation to get SNS Notification.

Answer (score -3):

You *can* trick CloudFormation into sending SNS messages from inside the template:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

> Custom resources enable you to write custom provisioning logic in
>   templates that AWS CloudFormation runs anytime you create, update (if
>   you changed the custom resource), or delete stacks. For example, you
>   might want to include resources that aren't available as AWS
>   CloudFormation resource types. You can include those resources by
>   using custom resources. That way you can still manage all your related
>   resources in a single stack.
>
> Use the AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource or Custom::String resource
>   type to define custom resources in your templates. Custom resources
>   require one property: the service token, which specifies where AWS
>   CloudFormation sends requests to, **such as an Amazon SNS topic**.

Comment: no. no. no.   Custom resources require you to respond otherwise the cf template is blocked for _hours_ waiting for completion/failure.

Comment: Custom resources were created to handle outside resources. Besides what @Dan mentioned , which is that you will be blocking (!) on the stack creation, you will also only get Create/Update/Destroy notifications, not the full event logs of the stack