# aws cloudformation send SNS to existing topic once stack is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to send message to existing SNS topic, but only once CF stack is completed. When I set SNS it is send right away once stack is started.

Can someone point to solution?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664226/how-to-send-sns-notification-after-cloud-formation-is-completed

Comment: Maybe there is another solution to trigger Lambda only after CloudFormation stack is completed?