# How can I catch CloudFormation stack CREATE_COMPLETED event and handle it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating CloudFormation stack and Lambda that I want to be invoked once stack creation has been completed (stack gained CREATE_COMPLETED status). Lambda is not stack resource, but this can be changed to achieve result if needed.

Is it possible to catch this event for stack using CloudWatchRule?

Currently I am able to catch stack resources creation events, but not stack creation itself.

Similar questions include approaches of subscribing CloudFormationTemplate to SNS topic, however this triggers SNS on each stack resource status change, but not stack itself.

Given this, Lambda will be invoked on each resource change, which doesnt tell anything about whole template status.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trigger a lambda on creation from CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template)

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [How to send SNS notification after cloud formation is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664226/how-to-send-sns-notification-after-cloud-formation-is-completed) and [Is it possible to trigger a lambda on creation from CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350483/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-lambda-on-creation-from-cloudformation-template)

CloudWatch Rules is not the solution here as Rules are triggered by limited set of services or API calls.  (see the list here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html)

The solution is to hook your Cloudformation tempate to an SNS topic (see doc here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html) and link SNS to a Lambda function.

You will receive message like the below

```
StackId='arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:99999999999:stack/test/b08a8460-368c-11e9-be1f-025fe09a8a16'
Timestamp='2019-02-22T10:30:41.127Z'
EventId='e710f3c0-368c-11e9-b22d-06366d428b7a'
LogicalResourceId='test'
Namespace='486652066693'
PhysicalResourceId='arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:486652066693:stack/test/b08a8460-368c-11e9-be1f-025fe09a8a16'
PrincipalId='AID....6SK'
ResourceProperties='null'
ResourceStatus='CREATE_COMPLETE'
ResourceStatusReason=''
ResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
StackName='test'
ClientRequestToken='Console-CreateStack-c305c793-9a83-b175-bd26-f251aee30adc'
```

Comment: I understood approach proposed, but still when stack is subscribed to SNS topic, SNS is trigered for each stack resource event, but not for stack itself.I am getting Lambda invoked per each stack resource, and never get event of stack being completed itself.

Comment: You're correct - the status of the stack itself does not trigger notifications - and the other answers listed at the top of my answer address this.  For example: create a lambda function in your template, with proper `dependsOn` property to ensure it is created last and invoke it on the CREATE_COMPLETE resource notification. All of these are hacky workaround, this is not elegant.  Why are you trying to do this ?  There might be a better way to trigger code at the end ?

Comment: Thanx for your attention. I do it as I want other people to be notified about stack completion using their tools like slack. They must be notified of stack outputs so that they can start using stack resources and know credentials/ip/etc